# When should I write my own Look and Feel for Java Swing instead of customizing one?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have used a few different Look and Feels for Java Swing, but I don't really like anyone to 100% so I often end up with customizing it a lot. Sometimes I am thinking about if it is a better idea to write my own LaF (by extending an existing one), but I don't really know.

For the moment, I mostly use [Nimbus](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/java6u10/#nimbus), but I change all colors (to darker ones) and rewrite the appearance of some components, like [sliders](http://www.jasperpotts.com/blog/2008/08/skinning-a-slider-with-nimbus/) and scrollbars. I also mostly customize all tables and I am thinking about to change the look of a few other components.

When is it recommended to create a new Look-and-Feel instead of customizing one? What are the pros and cons?

I.e. customize Nimbus or create a new one by extending Nimbus?

Related article: [Creating a Custom Look and Feel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html) (old)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When is it recommended to create a new Look-and-Feel instead of customizing one?

- When you want your app to look really nearly exactly the same on every major platform
- When you want to get rid of "dead giveaways" that your app is a Java app (which is a concern for quite some programmers selling commercial software for OS X users, where Java has a terribly bad rep amongst users [it's undeserved, but it's a fact]).

Here's an example of the kind of sickness you have to go through to enhance a tiny bit the pathetic JTable (btw the author of this blog later got hired by Apple):

http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/creating-a-better-jtable/

> What are the pros?

It is possible to make an app look nearly identical (the only difference being the font rendering, which slightly varies from OS X to Linux to Windows... but it can be made to be quite close, or you can go with "non AA" pixel-perfect fonts, that will look perfectly identical).

> and cons?

- You're app won't have a native look at all.
- It's a lot of work (Swing ain't exactly easy: it's some kind of over-engineered, over-complicated beast and it's very difficult to tell if it's "incredibly smartly designed" or "incredibly dumbly designed").

I've written several custom Swing components looking **exactly** the same on Windows, Linux and OS X (using pixel-perfect fonts) but I wouldn't write an entire LnF.

Comment: Thanks. The last few lines was helpful.

Comment: +1, great answer! As someone who has written a customized L&F library on top of Swing, I can attest to much of the pain associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any answers to this question except for generalities like:

- when the effort of applying the changes to the existing Look-and-Feel is greater than creating a new one, or
- when you want to create a new Look-and-Feel for non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a Java look and feel is not for the faint of heart. It's an endeavor in itself, which is why I'd say that it's probably more efficient to find a pre-existing look and feel that suits your needs.

Kathryn Huxtable has been working on the implementation of the [Sea Glass Look and Feel](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/), which has been quite an undertaking. It's based on Nimbus, though Nimbus and it's Swing underpinnings are not nearly as extensible as is required to create a custom look and feel. That means that much of the code must be copied and pasted into sub-classes. You likely don't want to get side-tracked with this kind of thing, when working on another project.

[Synthetica](http://www.jyloo.com/synthetica/screenshots/blackeye/) is also another pre-existing option, which I believe is quite skin-able.